# Box shadow button in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: **enter image description here**]

I need like that button in react native ..it's possible??

I need to set press animation after clicking button like in below url..

**https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate3**

Comment: So what's the problem? Try asking more specifically. What have you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: I tried something about creating buttons with box-shadow using elavation and shadow property..that not looks like that..Can you please explain how to do that button pressed effect?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give elevation prop to View

```
<View elevation={5} style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Hello World !</Text>
</View>
```

**styles can be added like this :**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 container:{
    padding:20,
    backgroundColor:'#d9d9d9',
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 1
    }
   },
 })
```